# ¿Como dar formato a una fecha Highcharts?

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito dar formato a una fecha solo quiero mostrar la fecha nada mas sin las horas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi respuesta en la consulta

```
 DIA
13/11/2018
12/11/2018
11/11/2018
10/11/2018
09/11/2018
08/11/2018
07/11/2018
06/11/2018
```

Este es mi codigo

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            chartCPU = new Highcharts.chart('graf', 
            {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'AA'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    categories: 
                    [
                        <?php
                            foreach($param['DIA'] as $dia)
                            {
                                echo "'$dia',";
                            }
                        ?>
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: 
                [
                    {
                        min: 0,
                        title: 
                        {
                            text: '',
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        title: 
                        {
                            text: '',
                        },
                        opposite: true
                    }
                ],
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                  enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    split: true
                },
                series: 
                [
                    {
                        name: 'TOTAL',
                        yAxis: 0,
                        data: 
                        [
                            <?php 
                                for ($j=0; $j < count($param['TOTAL_MT']) ; $j++) 
                                { 
                                    echo $param['TOTAL_MT'][$j].','; 
                                }
                            ?>
                        ],
                        color: '#FF7F50',
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                    },{
                        name: 'RATE',
                        yAxis: 1,
                        data: 
                        [
                            <?php 
                                for ($k=0; $k < count($param['RATE_MT']) ; $k++) 
                                { 
                                    echo $param['RATE_MT'][$k].','; 
                                }
                            ?>
                        ],
                        color: '#5F9EA0',
                        cursor: 'pointer'
                    }
                ]
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Hola Juan. Podrias copiar el codigo JavaScript puro? Seria mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola. Ese es el codigo puro que tengo asi me muestra la imagen que coloque arriba lo unico que quiero quitar son los 00:00:00 ya que solo quiero mostrar la fecha

Answer (score 0):

En el atributo xAxis agrega la etiqueta `dateTimeLabelFormats`. Dentro de la misma puedes definir el formato en que quieres que se muestren dichas etiquetas. En tu caso que las etiquetas muestran los segundos, modifica la etiqueta `second`:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        second: '%d-%m-%Y',
    }
}
```

Además podrás definir también diferentes intervalos de tiempo y como quieres que se muestren en el gráfico.

Te dejo el link de referencia oficial donde podrás encontrar más información al respecto:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: Voy a probar te aviso cualquiera cosa

Comment: Nada igual mira esto es lo que me muestra el resultado "xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: '%d-%m-%Y',
      },
      categories: 
      [
       '2018-11-13 00:00:00','2018-11-12 00:00:00','2018-11-11 00:00:00','2018-11-10 00:00:00','2018-11-09 00:00:00','2018-11-08 00:00:00','2018-11-07 00:00:00','2018-11-06 00:00:00',      ]
     },"

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta. En vez de day, usa la palabra "second" y me contás.

Comment: Lo muestra igual con la nueva modificacion que me enviaste.